# Ledger for Exterior Stairs - Attach to Existing Wood or Remove and Add Ledger

Tags: deck, stairs, ledger

I'm adding steps to the exterior of my house. I know the steps need to be attached to a ledger. However, I cannot decide what the white piece of wood that is already there:

- Is it a ledger without the bolts; thus, I just need to add the bolts?
- Is it just a cover that I need to pry off (it's nailed in pretty good)?
- Can I just attach the stair hangers to?

[image: Existing Wood]

Comment: Is it possible to get a wider shot so we can see what's above it? If there's a door above it the white piece could be a part of the frame.

Comment: The white piece is about 6 to 8 inches tall and it’s a sliding glass door above it. The sliding glass door has a wooden fence in front of it. I’ll post a larger picture when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board is a fascia board, which hides the rim joist.  It's only nailed or screwed in.  I need to remove it, so I can attach the ledger.

Comment: If you have direct access to the rim joist, a ledger isn't necessarily required. As long as everything is flashed appropriately for water drainage, you may fasten your deck joists directly to the rim joist.